# Check previously clicked radio button

Tags: javascript

I have a form having multiple radio buttons in different groups. e.g 
category vehicle has two radio buttons

1. 2 wheeler
2. 4 wheeler

same as other categories have 2-2 radio buttons.

What i want to do is when i check 4 wheeler from 2 wheeler i show a warning message pop up, are u sure to switch, if yes then ok, but for no i want to check again 2 wheeler radio button. I can not do this from id as well coz i have to do this on other fields as well.

```
<input type="radio"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is not very clear but from what I understand I guess you want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit_button').click(function() {
    if (!$("input[@name='radioName']:checked").val()) {
     alert('Nothing is checked!');
    return false;
    }
else {
  alert('One of the radio buttons is checked!');
}
 });
 });
```

And add the same name tag for all your radio inputs:

```
<input type="radio" name="radioName"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're trying to achieve:

```
var old_input = $('input[name="wheeler"]:checked');
$('input[name="wheeler"]').change(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    if (
        old_input.next().text() == '2 Wheeler' &&
        $(this).next().text() == '4 Wheeler'
    ) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to change?')) {
            old_input = $(this);
        }
        else {
            this.checked = 0;
            old_input.get()[0].checked = 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        old_input = $(this);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pQpk7/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/7rF3d/ When a radio button is checked for the first time nothing happens. When someone checked another he is first prompted for a confirmation. If the user cancels the old checked radio will be restored.

```
var lastChecked;

$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {

    if(typeof(lastChecked) != "undefined" && !confirm("are you sure?")) {

        $("input[type=radio]:checked").attr("checked", "false");

        $(lastChecked).prop("checked", true);

    } else {

        lastChecked = $('input[type=radio]:checked');

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since jQuery isn't tagged in the question, here's a pure JS approach. Guys, seriously, try to quit suggesting jQuery solutions when it isn't even tagged in the question.

You can achieve this by using the `click` event and returning false if there is at least one radio button checked, then the answer to a `window.confirm` is false, which will prevent it to select the new one as expected.

```
var oneChecked=false;
var elem=document.getElementsByName("wheeler");

for (var i=0;i<elem.length;i++) {
   elem[i].onclick=function(e) {
       if (oneChecked && !window.confirm("Are you sure to switch?")) {
           return false;
       } else {
           oneChecked=true;
       }
   }
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q787H/)